# How to store command return values in bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a command which upon execution return me set of numbers which I want to store in a bash array.

```
    vihaan@trojan:~/trash$ xdotool search brain 
Defaulting to search window name, class, and classname
52428804
50331651
62914564
65011896
48234499
```

How do I store these values in an array ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this simple case:

```
array=( $(xdotool search brain) )
```

If the output were more complicated (for example, the lines might have spaces in them), you can use the bash builtin `mapfile`:

```
mapfile -t array < <(xdotool search brain)
```

(`help mapfile` for more information)

Answer (score 4):

```
declare -a myarr  # declare an array
myarr=($(grep -v "Defaulting" $(xdotool search brain) | awk '{printf $1" "}'))  # Fill the array with all the numbers from the command line
echo ${myarr[*]}  # echo all the elements of the array
```

OR

```
echo ${myarr[1]}  # First element of the array
```

Comment: The `grep -v` is harmless but unnecessary: that line is sent to `stderr`, not `stdout`. You shouldn't use `printf` in awk when you mean `print` for the same reason you shouldn't do that in C: there might be a percent in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could write another command the expects input and puts said input into an array. So you would pipe the output from the first command to your `toArray` command. Then do what you need to with the `toArray` output.